Plotly scatter plot updates slow when data rate is < 100ms
I am facing an issues in updating plotly trace with <100ms.
My case is like feeding data at higher speed at 10x or 20x ploltly update is happening at normal speed irrespective of selected speed.
Data size is about 4100 samples everytime on updating plotly scatter plot.
Till 5x speed which is 200ms of data feed working fine.
Issue is with >5x speed.
Looking for solutions or suggestions.
tried Worker threads to speed up the calculations but didn't work.
calculation part for the data framing is taking 20ms
